# OpenERP v7 on_change function returns number instead of value

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

```
 def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, context=None):
     val = {
         'name': product_id,
     }

 return {'value': val}


    <field name="product_id" on_change="onchange_product_id(product_id, context)"/>
    <field name="name"/>
```

I have the value in one2many (product1, product2) when I select 'product2' the function `onchange_product_id` returns the value of 2 instead of product2 and it appears on field `'name'`.
This is only happens when I am using on_change in many2one,one2many.... relationship but in char,int and float the value of function returns correct.

My question is how can I get the correct value of one2many using on_change function ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like ,

```
def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, context=None):
    product = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)
    val = {
         'name': product and product.name or '',
    }

    return {'value': val}
```

Because **product_id** contains and id not the browsable record. So first you need to browse that record and then need to fetch the name of product.

Comment: But it gives me an error.... TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Sorry I have used search instead of browse, in new api search will give you browsable. Try updated answer

Comment: Gotcha... awesome ... :)